# Contravariance generic interface, and a wall I keep running into

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance

I have a class `Company` that holds a list of different `IFactory<IPart>`; e.g. an `EngineFactory`.

```
public class Company
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IFactory<IPart>> _factories;

    public Company()
    {
        _factories = new Dictionary<Type, IFactory<IPart>>();
        _factories[typeof (Engine)] = new EngineFactory();
    }

    public void SendOrderIntakeToFactory(IPart part)
    {
    }
}
```

The `EngineFactory` looks like this:

```
public class EngineFactory : IFactory<Engine> 
{
    public void Produce(Engine part)
    {
    }
}
```

And the `IFactory` interface:

```
public interface IFactory<T> where T : IPart
{
    void Produce(T part);
}
```

This will result in a compiler error:

> > Cannot implicitly convert type 'EngineFactory' to 'IFactory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

on this line: `_factories[typeof (Engine)] = new EngineFactory();`

Ok that makes sense to me, without specifying the variance this will never work. So I tried to add the `out` keyword to the generic type `T`, but that will force me to remove the `T` as method parameter (because it's not allowed to use `<out T>` as input parameter):

```
public interface IFactory<out T> where T : IPart
{
    void Produce(IPart part);
}
```

This clearly breaks my generic design. I am able to produce `Wheel`s at my `EngineFactory`.

I understand the challenge lies in these two requirements:

- Store the factory as `IFactory<IPart>`
- The need for a generic `void Produce(T part);` implementation in the factories.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want engine-factory to produce a part (and return it)... or do something when given a part?

Comment: Name isnt brilliant i admit. But i want to pass a parameter and produce it based on the input. So the given answer doesnt help me yet :)

Comment: @bas what 'produce it' means? You want to modify it?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky the `IPart` is the ticket description of an engine e.g.. So a better signature would be `IPart Produce(IPartTicket)`. I will update the question as soon as a I get to my PC (on phone now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark generic type parameter as covariant if it used only as return type of methods. Change `Produce` method to return part and all will work

```
public interface IFactory<out T> where T : IPart
{
    T Produce();
}
```

You can't use covariant type parameter if it is used as method parameter.

BTW it's really strange factory which accepts objects instead of creating them.

---

UPDATE you can use runtime type definition with dynamic:

```
public class Company
{
    private Dictionary<Type, dynamic> _factories;

    public Company()
    {
        _factories = new Dictionary<Type, dynamic>();
        _factories[typeof(Engine)] = new EngineFactory();
    }

    public void SendOrderIntakeToFactory(IPart part)
    {
        _factories[part.GetType()].Produce((dynamic)part);
    }
}
```

When you will call

```
company.SendOrderIntakeToFactory(new Engine());
```

Then `EngineFactory` will be selected and it's `Produce` method will be called with parameter of runtime type `Engine`.

Comment: From what OP has given, it isn't a factory; its a service

Comment: Its the order that goes to the factory. You are right.that it should produce something, but my problem idd lies with the parameter. It shouldnt be a result type.

Comment: @bas updated my answer. Your code will work if types will be defined at runtime (also remove `out` parameter form generic type)

Comment: Why the overhead of `dynamic` when `object` will do? (no, I did not downvote, but introducing dynamic here seems really unneccesary)

Comment: @PeterLillevold object will not have method `Produce`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - ah, yes I see now. But: as long as you are in control of what goes into the dictionary you can safely cast to `IFactory...`

Comment: @PeterLillevold benefit is that my code can process list of any `IPart` implementations. There could be Engine, Wheel, Door. Thus method is not generic, any part which has registered factory, will be processed (actually there should be logic for checking if type is registered in dictionary, I omitted it as irrelevant for question)

Comment: +1 for dynamic (haven't even thought of that). Thx for the insights so far (complex stuff this contravariance concept!)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could loosen up the dictionary a bit. Consider the following "factory container":

```
public class Factories
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _factories;

    public Factories()
    {
        _factories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        _factories[typeof (Engine)] = new EngineFactory();
    }

    public IFactory<TPart> GetFactory<TPart>() where TPart:IPart
    {
        //TODO: add check whether typeof(TPart) exist in the dictionary
        return (IFactory<TPart>)_factories[typeof(TPart)];
    }
}
```

This implementation would allow you to do the following:

```
var factories = new Factories();
var engineFactory = factories.GetFactory<Engine>();
var engine = new Engine();
engineFactory.Produce(engine);
```

Comment: And there lies the only solution to the problem (in general); namely move the type checking to run-time and storing `objects`.

Comment: @Peter +1. It seems that there is no way to get a solution with the two given design constraints... I'll give it some more time, and in the meantime try to understand the concepts of contravariance better.

Comment: @bas - indeed, these things can be hard to mix. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you are specifically trying to do (mixing covariance and contra-variance) is a **rabbit hole**. The only solution is **NOT** to mix variance like this; Move to run-time type checking when you feel the need to mix variance.

[Updated] This would deal with both concerns (strongly typed and flexible location)

```
interface IPart{}
class Engine : IPart{} 

interface IMachine
{
    void Produce(IPart part);
    Type Type { get; }
}

interface IGenericMachine<in TPart> : IMachine
{
    void Produce(TPart with);
}

class EngineMachine : IGenericMachine<Engine>
{
    public void Produce(Engine with)
    {
    }

    public void Produce(IPart part)
    {
        if (part.GetType() != typeof(Engine))
            throw new ArgumentException("part must be an Engine");
    }

    public Type Type { get { return typeof (Engine); } }
}

internal class MachineLocator
{
    public Dictionary<Type, IMachine> Machines;

    public IGenericMachine<TPart> GetMachine<TPart>()
    {
        return Machines
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .OfType<IGenericMachine<TPart>>()
            .Single();
    }

    public IMachine GetMachine(Type type)
    {
        return Machines
            .Where(x => x.Value.Type == type)
            .Select(x=>x.Value)
            .Single();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        var locator = new MachineLocator();

        locator.Machines.Add(typeof(EngineMachine), new EngineMachine());

        var machineKnown = locator.GetMachine<Engine>();
        var machineUnknown = locator.GetMachine(typeof(Engine));

        machineUnknown.Produce(new Engine());
    }
}
```

When all is said and done; have a look at *Inversion of Control* as a better design pattern for your program in general. Basically classes don't look for stuff, they get given it.

Comment: So where is your solution to the `Company.SendOrderIntakeToFactory` method? Your code is explicitly running the order through a worker that is explicit on what type of part it supports. The OP needs the entry to accept the common `IPart` interface.

Comment: +1, still trying to compile this in my head, but I see your point. I will study the topic some more and then come back here